# Javascript bin-packing problem is leaving empty spaces

Tags: javascript, canvas

My friend and I are working on a small project, but are struggling with bin-packing problem using canvas drawing, to let the customers imagine, what they're ordering.

It's basically a PCB order form. What we are struggling with is that the canvas is somehow drawing "stairs" in the middle of the image, when adding patterns.

I can find no good reason why this is happening.

```
/*-- CLASSES --*/

let GrowingPacker = function() { };

GrowingPacker.prototype = {

  fit: function(blocks) {
    var n, node, block, len = blocks.length;
    var w = len > 0 ? blocks[0].w : 0;
    var h = len > 0 ? blocks[0].h : 0;
    this.root = { x: 0, y: 0, w: w, h: h };
    for (n = 0; n < len ; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h))
        block.fit = this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h);
      else
        block.fit = this.growNode(block.w, block.h);
    }
  },

  findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
      return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    else if ((w <= root.w) && (h <= root.h))
      return root;
    else
      return null;
  },

  splitNode: function(node, w, h) {
    node.used = true;
    node.down  = { x: node.x,     y: node.y + h, w: node.w,     h: node.h - h };
    node.right = { x: node.x + w, y: node.y,     w: node.w - w, h: h          };
    return node;
  },

  growNode: function(w, h) {
    //var possibleGrowDown = (limit.area.max.height >= this.root.h + h);
    var possibleGrowRight = (limit.area.max.width >= this.root.w + w);
    
    var canGrowDown  = (w <= this.root.w);
    var canGrowRight = (h <= this.root.h);

    var shouldGrowDown  = possibleGrowRight && canGrowDown  && (this.root.w >= (this.root.h + h)); // attempt to keep square-ish by growing down  when width  is much greater than height
    var shouldGrowRight = possibleGrowRight && canGrowRight && (this.root.h >= (this.root.w + w)); // attempt to keep square-ish by growing right when height is much greater than width
    
    if (shouldGrowDown)
      return this.growDown(w, h);
    else if (shouldGrowRight)
      return this.growRight(w, h);
    else if (canGrowDown)
      return this.growDown(w, h);
    else if (canGrowRight)
     return this.growRight(w, h);
    else
      return null; // need to ensure sensible root starting size to avoid this happening
  },

  growRight: function(w, h) {
    this.root = {
      used: true,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: this.root.w + w,
      h: this.root.h,
      down: this.root,
      right: { x: this.root.w, y: 0, w: w, h: this.root.h }
    };
    var node;
    if (node = this.findNode(this.root, w, h))
      return this.splitNode(node, w, h);
    else
      return null;
  },

  growDown: function(w, h) {
    this.root = {
      used: true,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: this.root.w,
      h: this.root.h + h,
      down:  { x: 0, y: this.root.h, w: this.root.w, h: h },
      right: this.root
    };
    var node;
    if (node = this.findNode(this.root, w, h))
      return this.splitNode(node, w, h);
    else
      return null;
  }

}

class Line {
    strokeStyle = '#ddd';
    
    constructor(fX, fY, tX, tY) {
        this.fX = fX;
        this.fY = fY;
        this.tX = tX;
        this.tY = tY;
    }
    
    get length() {
        const hL = Math.pow(this.tX - this.fX, 2);
        const vL = Math.pow(this.tY - this.fY, 2);
        const l = Math.sqrt(hL + vL);
        return l;
    }
    
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.fX, this.fY);
        ctx.lineTo(this.tX, this.tY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

class Base {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    w = 0;
    h = 0;
    fillStyle = '#e0ede0';
    strokeStyle = '#0d0';
    
    constructor() {}
    
    resize(canvas, motifs) {
        let x = canvas.width;
        let y = canvas.height;
        let w = 0;
        let h = 0;
        
        if(motifs && motifs.length > 0) {
            motifs.forEach((motif) => {
                if(motif.x < x) { x = motif.x; }
                if(motif.y < y) { y = motif.y; }
                if(motif.x + motif.w > x + w) { w = motif.x - x + motif.w; }
                if(motif.y + motif.h > y + h) { h = motif.y - y + motif.h; }
            });
        }
        else {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        
        this.x = x - form.option.panelization[1].padding;
        this.y = y - form.option.panelization[1].padding;
        this.w = w + form.option.panelization[1].padding * 2;
        this.h = h + form.option.panelization[1].padding * 2;
    }
    
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

class Motif {
    name = 'A';
    subname = 1;
    quantity = 1;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    w = 0;
    h = 0;
    fillStyle = '#ede0e0';
    strokeStyle = '#d00';
    
    constructor(id, subname='1') {
        this.id = id;
        this.subname = subname;
    }
    
    get fullName() {
        return this.name + this.subname;
    }
    
    get id() {
        return this.number;
    }
    
    set id(id) {
        this.number = id;
        
        this.generateName();
    }
    
    get area() {
        return this.w * this.h;
    }
    
    generateName() {
        let num = this.number;
        let s = '', t;
        
        while(num > 0) {
            t = (num - 1) % 26;
            s = String.fromCharCode(65 + t) + s;
            num = (num - t) / 26 | 0;
        }
        
        this.name = s;
    }
    
    rotate() {
        const w = this.w;
        this.w = this.h;
        this.h = w;
    }
    
    draw(ctx) {
        // Rectangle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        ctx.stroke();
        
        // Text
        ctx.fillStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        ctx.font = '12px Arial';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillText(this.fullName, this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.h / 2);
    }
}

class Canvas {
    canvas;
    ctx;
    
    gridCellSize = 10;
    gridLines = [];
    
    base = new Base();
    motifs = [];
    millingLines = [];
    
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        // Create grid lines
        for(let i = 0; i < this.canvas.width / this.gridCellSize + 1; i++) {
            this.gridLines.push(new Line(i * this.gridCellSize, 0, i * this.gridCellSize, this.canvas.height));
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < this.canvas.height / this.gridCellSize + 1; i++) {
            this.gridLines.push(new Line(0, i * this.gridCellSize, this.canvas.width, i * this.gridCellSize));
        }
        
        this.update();
    }
    
    update(motifs) {
        this.motifs = motifs;
        
        this.arrangeMotifs();
        
        this.base.resize(this.canvas, this.motifs);
        
        this.draw();
    }
    
    arrangeMotifs() {
        if(form.option.panelization[1].motifs.length > 0) {
            // Copy motifs
            let motifs = [];
            form.option.panelization[1].motifs.forEach((motif) => {
                if(motif.w > 0 && motif.h > 0) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < motif.quantity; i++) {
                        const motifCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(motif));
                        const motifCopyKeys = Object.keys(motifCopy);
                        const motifCopyValues = Object.values(motifCopy);
                        
                        let newMotif = new Motif(motifCopy.id);
                        for(let i = 0; i < motifCopyKeys.length; i++) {
                            newMotif[motifCopyKeys[i]] = motifCopyValues[i];
                        }
                        newMotif.subname = i+1;
                        newMotif.x = 0;
                        newMotif.y = 0;
                        if(newMotif.w > newMotif.h) {
                            newMotif.rotate();
                        }
                        // Add milling padding
                        newMotif.w += limit.milling;
                        newMotif.h += limit.milling;
                        motifs.push(newMotif);
                    }
                }
            });
            
            // Place motifs
            const baseW = limit.area.max.width - limit.milling - form.option.panelization[1].padding * 2;
            const baseH = limit.area.max.height - limit.milling - form.option.panelization[1].padding * 2;
            this.motifs = this.placeMotifs(motifs, baseW, baseH);
        }
    }
    
    placeMotifs(motifs, baseW, baseH) {
        // Sort by area
        motifs.sort((a, b) => b.area - a.area);
        
        // Sort by max(width, height)
        motifs.sort((a, b) => Math.max(b.w, b.h) - Math.max(a.w, a.h));
        
        // Packing motifs
        const packer = new GrowingPacker();
        packer.fit(motifs);
        
        const finalMotifs = [];
        
        motifs.forEach((motif) => {
            const motifCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(motif));
            const motifCopyKeys = Object.keys(motifCopy);
            const motifCopyValues = Object.values(motifCopy);
            
            let newMotif = new Motif(motifCopy.id);
            for(let i = 0; i < motifCopyKeys.length; i++) {
                newMotif[motifCopyKeys[i]] = motifCopyValues[i];
            }
            // Fix x & y
            if(motif.fit) {
                newMotif.x = motif.fit.x;
                newMotif.y = motif.fit.y;
            }
            // Add padding
            newMotif.x += form.option.panelization[1].padding;
            newMotif.y += form.option.panelization[1].padding;
            // Milling
            newMotif.w -= limit.milling;
            newMotif.h -= limit.milling;
            finalMotifs.push(newMotif);
        });
        
        return finalMotifs;
    }
    
    draw() {
        // Clear
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        
        // Grid lines
        if(this.gridLines && this.gridLines.length > 0) {
            this.gridLines.forEach((line) => {
                line.draw(this.ctx);
            });
        }
        
        // Text
        this.ctx.fillStyle = '#888';
        this.ctx.font = '12px Arial';
        this.ctx.textAlign = 'right';
        this.ctx.textBaseline = 'baseline';
        this.ctx.fillText(this.canvas.width + 'x' + this.canvas.height + 'mm', this.canvas.width - 10, this.canvas.height - 10);
        
        // Base
        this.base.draw(this.ctx);
        
        // Motifs
        if(this.motifs && this.motifs.length > 0) {
            this.motifs.forEach((motif) => {
                motif.draw(this.ctx);
            });
        }
        
        // Milling lines
        if(this.millingLines && this.millingLines.length > 0) {
            this.millingLines.forEach((millingLine) => {
                millingLine.draw(this.ctx);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Live preview:
http://jadvo.eu/

Panelized pattern -> Add pattern (Keep clicking it to add more patterns and you will see what's the problem)

Comment: In function `GrowingPacker.growNode` the vars `canGrowDown` and  `canGrowRight` appear to be assigned the wrong axis. You have `canGrowDown  = (w <= this.root.w);` maybe it should be `canGrowDown  = (h <= this.root.h);` and same again, right should be  `canGrowRight = (w <= this.root.w)` rather than `canGrowRight = (h <= this.root.h)`

Comment: You're right... That solved our problem. Thanks a lot!